# Are static variables in a function bad?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, code-optimization

For my code I use a couple of static variables.
But when I search the internet, they seem "evil".

For example: I have a function which will be executed every loop (5ms looptime).
to increase the speed I added some static variables to it.
Is the way I am doing this bad? Are there simple solutions for it?

Code:

```
int ProgFormula() {
  static int StartPosition;
  static int DeltaPosition;
  static int LoopTime = 5;
  static int AccelerationLoops;
  static int TotalLoops;
  static int EndOne;

  static float VelocityLoop;
  static float VelocityFactor;

  int Setpoint;

  if (Iteration == -1) {
    StartPosition = PID.ActualPosition;
    DeltaPosition = abs(SetPosition - StartPosition);
    VelocityLoop = Velocity / (1000 / LoopTime);
    TotalLoops = DeltaPosition / VelocityLoop;
    if (TotalLoops <= (AccelerationLoops * 2)) {
      AccelerationLoops = (TotalLoops / 2);
      VelocityFactor = (VelocityLoop * 0.5 / AccelerationLoops) / 2;
    }
    else {
      AccelerationLoops = 70;

      VelocityFactor = VelocityLoop * 0.5 / AccelerationLoops;
    }
    TotalLoops = DeltaPosition / VelocityLoop + AccelerationLoops;
    EndOne = (VelocityFactor * pow(AccelerationLoops, 2));
  }
  else if (Iteration >= 0 && Iteration <= AccelerationLoops) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = VelocityFactor * pow(Iteration, 2) + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = -VelocityFactor * pow(Iteration, 2) + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else if (Iteration > AccelerationLoops && Iteration <= (TotalLoops - AccelerationLoops)) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = VelocityLoop * Iteration - EndOne + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = -VelocityLoop * Iteration + EndOne + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else if (Iteration >= (TotalLoops - AccelerationLoops) && Iteration <= TotalLoops) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = -VelocityFactor * pow((TotalLoops - Iteration), 2) + DeltaPosition + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = VelocityFactor * pow((TotalLoops - Iteration), 2) - DeltaPosition + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else {
    Setpoint = Setpoint;
  }
  return(Setpoint);
}
```

Is it better to avoid statics? If so why?

Thanks in advance,
Koen

Comment: Why do you need static variables in the above example? I can't see them being any use here. If you just want a variable that you can change easily because you're 'tweaking' your code (e.g. changing LoopTime so you get as many loops per second without compromising accuracy) then pull that variable into global scope; you can `#define <name> <value>` or `const <Type> <name> = <value>`. These declarations/definitions get 'smoothed out' by the compiler and so don't take up any program memory.

Comment: `to increase the speed I added some static variables to it.` - how does that increase the speed?

Comment: `pow(AccelerationLoops, 2)` - you want fast speed but then you call a function that will be slow?

Comment: I am still a newbie haha, hmm better replace that pow function...

Comment: No but my idea was to calculate some variables infront (iteration -1) how could i use those  otherwise?

Comment: So you mean you want to 'create' variables so that they already exist before you start the beefy calculations, thus saving time? I don't think it works like that. All the calculations after the `if (iteration == 1)` is going to get torn apart by the compiler and then rearranged as optimally as it thinks it can be. If you need execution of these to be quicker, you *might* be better off asking in StackOverflow, as this topic transcends Arduino and is definitely within the realm of programmers and compilers.

Comment: That too, but I actually meant the calculations of the statics at iteration == -1. Won't this save? If not, I can make those local

Comment: I understand better what you are attempting now. I gather you call the function with `Iteration == -1` at some stage to "preload" the static variables, and then multiple times with other iteration values. To answer better we would need to know how often you do that. For example, do you do 1000 iterations before re-calculating the static variables? Or three iterations? Judging by the fact that you get `PID.ActualPosition` in the "preload" part, you must be calling it with `Iteration == -1` reasonably often.

Comment: Hello Nick, yes you are right, when the function "starts up" it is calledwith Iteration -1. The amount of iterations it takes is depended on the DeltaPosition and the Velocity. Normally this will 500+

Comment: There is no point in making `LoopTime` static, as it is set on every call to the function. The whole point of `static` is to make sure the contents of the variable is preserved between calls. Static locals are much like globals in this respect, only they have a restricted scope. On the other hand, `Setpoint` should probably be static, otherwise it seems it may be returned uninitialized. And the line `Setpoint = Setpoint;` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I made up a test by adding enough to the posted code to get it to compile:

```C++
float ActualPosition, SetPosition, Velocity;

int Iteration;

int ProgFormula() {

  static int StartPosition;
  static int DeltaPosition;
  static int LoopTime = 5;
  static int AccelerationLoops;
  static int TotalLoops;
  static int EndOne;

  static float VelocityLoop;
  static float VelocityFactor;

  int Setpoint;

  if (Iteration == -1) {
    StartPosition = ActualPosition;
    DeltaPosition = abs(SetPosition - StartPosition);
    VelocityLoop = Velocity / (1000 / LoopTime);
    TotalLoops = DeltaPosition / VelocityLoop;
    if (TotalLoops <= (AccelerationLoops * 2)) {
      AccelerationLoops = (TotalLoops / 2);
      VelocityFactor = (VelocityLoop * 0.5 / AccelerationLoops) / 2;
    }
    else {
      AccelerationLoops = 70;

      VelocityFactor = VelocityLoop * 0.5 / AccelerationLoops;
    }
    TotalLoops = DeltaPosition / VelocityLoop + AccelerationLoops;
    EndOne = (VelocityFactor * pow(AccelerationLoops, 2));
  }
  else if (Iteration >= 0 && Iteration <= AccelerationLoops) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = VelocityFactor * pow(Iteration, 2) + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = -VelocityFactor * pow(Iteration, 2) + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else if (Iteration > AccelerationLoops && Iteration <= (TotalLoops - AccelerationLoops)) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = VelocityLoop * Iteration - EndOne + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = -VelocityLoop * Iteration + EndOne + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else if (Iteration >= (TotalLoops - AccelerationLoops) && Iteration <= TotalLoops) {
    if (StartPosition < SetPosition) {
      Setpoint = -VelocityFactor * pow((TotalLoops - Iteration), 2) + DeltaPosition + StartPosition;
    }
    else {
      Setpoint = VelocityFactor * pow((TotalLoops - Iteration), 2) - DeltaPosition + StartPosition;
    }
  }
  else {
    Setpoint = Setpoint;
  }
  return(Setpoint);
}

void setup ()
  {
   ProgFormula ();
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {

  }  // end of loop
```

Disassembling this I got the following assembler:

```
000000a8 <_Z11ProgFormulav>:
  a8:   6f 92           push    r6
  aa:   7f 92           push    r7
  ac:   8f 92           push    r8
  ae:   9f 92           push    r9
  b0:   af 92           push    r10
  b2:   bf 92           push    r11
  b4:   cf 92           push    r12
  b6:   df 92           push    r13
  b8:   ef 92           push    r14
  ba:   ff 92           push    r15
  bc:   0f 93           push    r16
  be:   1f 93           push    r17
  c0:   cf 93           push    r28
  c2:   df 93           push    r29
  c4:   00 91 0c 01     lds r16, 0x010C
  c8:   10 91 0d 01     lds r17, 0x010D
  cc:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  ce:   0f 3f           cpi r16, 0xFF   ; 255
  d0:   18 07           cpc r17, r24
...
 4ec:   cb 01           movw    r24, r22
 4ee:   df 91           pop r29
 4f0:   cf 91           pop r28
 4f2:   1f 91           pop r17
 4f4:   0f 91           pop r16
 4f6:   ff 90           pop r15
 4f8:   ef 90           pop r14
 4fa:   df 90           pop r13
 4fc:   cf 90           pop r12
 4fe:   bf 90           pop r11
 500:   af 90           pop r10
 502:   9f 90           pop r9
 504:   8f 90           pop r8
 506:   7f 90           pop r7
 508:   6f 90           pop r6
 50a:   08 95           ret

0000050c <setup>:
```

So that function (ProgFormula) has taken up:

```
0x50a - 0xa8 = 1122 bytes
```

Now by removing the "static" declarations, like this:

```C++
   int StartPosition;
   int DeltaPosition;
   int LoopTime = 5;
   int AccelerationLoops;
   int TotalLoops;
   int EndOne;

   float VelocityLoop;
   float VelocityFactor;
```

It now compiles to:

```
000000a8 <_Z11ProgFormulav>:
  a8:   6f 92           push    r6
  aa:   7f 92           push    r7
  ac:   8f 92           push    r8
  ae:   9f 92           push    r9
  b0:   af 92           push    r10
  b2:   bf 92           push    r11
  b4:   cf 92           push    r12
  b6:   df 92           push    r13
  b8:   ef 92           push    r14
  ba:   ff 92           push    r15
  bc:   0f 93           push    r16
  be:   1f 93           push    r17
  c0:   cf 93           push    r28
  c2:   df 93           push    r29
  c4:   c0 91 04 01     lds r28, 0x0104
  c8:   d0 91 05 01     lds r29, 0x0105
  cc:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  ce:   cf 3f           cpi r28, 0xFF   ; 255
  d0:   d8 07           cpc r29, r24
...
 27e:   cb 01           movw    r24, r22
 280:   df 91           pop r29
 282:   cf 91           pop r28
 284:   1f 91           pop r17
 286:   0f 91           pop r16
 288:   ff 90           pop r15
 28a:   ef 90           pop r14
 28c:   df 90           pop r13
 28e:   cf 90           pop r12
 290:   bf 90           pop r11
 292:   af 90           pop r10
 294:   9f 90           pop r9
 296:   8f 90           pop r8
 298:   7f 90           pop r7
 29a:   6f 90           pop r6
 29c:   08 95           ret

0000029e <setup>:
```

That is now:

```
0x29e - 0xa8 = 502 bytes
```

---

### Conclusion

Adding "static" has made the function over **twice as long**. Presumably it is also slower. After all, those extra instructions have be doing *something*.

> to increase the speed I added some static variables to it.

Your belief that making variables static increases the speed does not seem to be supported.

Comment: Hmm that is a huge difference. Unfortunately that is not what I meant. When Iteration == -1, then those variables are calculated. These variables will be used in further iterations. Because I intitialized them as statics they remember their value, now these do not have to be calculated over and over again. But is it worth the memory loss?

Comment: Could you actually time the functions? I don't fully trust your assumption about longer code being slower, since it doesn't account for how much might be skipped/replayed by jumps.

Comment: @KoenR - can you please run a test and post the calculated values when `Iteration == -1`? I tried timing the two methods but without knowing what values you are using the results are pretty meaningless. Or you could simply time it yourself, by calling `micros()` at the start, and again at the end, subtract one from the other, and work out which is faster.

Comment: @BrettAM - you are quite right to not trust assumptions. I try not to make them if I can, however in this case without any knowledge of the figures involved, I had to guess.

Comment: @NickGammon timed the calculations. WOW! When using the static variables the calculation took +- 150 micros. Now if use it the formula without the statics it will take an astonishing 0 - 4 microseconds to calculate. Then I realised that the compiler still exists. All my variables were predefined (not changing). Now I runned it like it should, all the iterations with a static variable took 50 micros whereas the one without took 200 micros. In the end, statics are sometimes viable I guess

Comment: `When using the static variables the calculation took +- 150 micros.` - I'm not sure if you are saying it took more or less there. However it looks like static variables worked for you in this case. :) It is always nice to test these ideas. Sometimes it is hard to predict what the compiler will do to your code.

Comment: A lot what you are seeing here may be due to the the compiler's ability to keep local variables in registers rather than in memory.  In a situation where that does not apply (due to program complexity, architectural limits, or a `volatile` keyword), it may come down more to the availability of other base + offset indexing modes vs. stack pointer + offset ones.

Comment: You comparison is flawed because you replaced static variables with automatic variables, which changes the semantics of the program, as static variables remember their values between calls. C.f. the compilation warnings you get: “XXX may be used uninitialized in this function”. For the comparison to be fair, you have to replace the local statics with global variables. My tests show static variables have no size penalty.

Comment: `Your comparison` - whose? If I understand correctly the suggested code uses [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to save calculating things as often. The savings probably need to be measured empirically, because the cost of calculating the static variables (as opposed to register variables) would not be nil. Whether or not you get the benefit would depend on how often you have to recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

> to increase the speed I added some static variables to it. Is the way
>   I am doing this bad? ... Is it better to avoid statics? If so why?

I use this technique too ... IMHO it is neither good nor bad.  In a logger, for instance, all the wall clock time stamp information has to be looked up (perhaps time(0)), and formatted at least once in any given second.  I use function static variables to prevent duplicating that effort for the 10's to 100's (or even more on a really fast machine) of log entries that happen in the **same** second.

I suspect your saying "to increase speed" is what the other answers focus on, and many contributors in SE jump on the 'premature optimization' concept. I think you unintentionally misled them.

Maybe your audience would respond more positively to the term **'memoize'** ... this technique avoids some work (when it can).

And, just to be complete - Wikipedia agrees with you:

> In computing, memoization is an optimization technique used primarily
>   to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive
>   function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs
>   occur again.

Note 1. I think memoization implies that there is work that need not be duplicated every time through the function (sometimes only initialization) ... thus there often will be an if-clause to skip over the un-necessary work.

Note 2. static is not the only way to hold onto previous values, but is probably somewhat more appropriate for a function when you do not want a class object (to hold the previous values).

Note 3. 'memoize' has impact because it avoids work, and this speeds up the whole system.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. This function will be called every 5 milliseconds. So that is why I wanted to know which is faster. But next time better to call memoize

Answer (score 0):

Any style recommendation is going to be a bit subjective and conditional, but the biggest problem I see here is that the function can only be running one set of variables at a time. What if you wanted to do two of the task your `ProgFormula` function is a part of simultaneously? You have no way to switch the state of those variables between calls.

You could make a struct to store the state that your function modifies, that way the calling code could swap out the state between calls. Or you could wrap it in a class so the calling code can make as many instances as it needs and not worry about the data each owns.

As a side note, [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). The state you are storing is built with a few subtractions and divisions, but the `pow` function your loop sometimes calls may be the part dominating its running time.

Comment: I know it are some beefy calculations, for now those cannot be replaced. Luckely this function will not be called twice, once every loop. If one of the variables change then the Iteration starts at -1 again. I did remove the pow function, rather complex for a simple square